# How we can put button on map info window and make it clickable

Tags: android

`enter code here`How to put  button on map info window and make it clickable , i tried the following code :-

```
    `enter code here`if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11.0f));
        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {



            // final Get_Preference_model item =
            // this.countryList.get(position);
            for(int i=0;i<countryList.size();i++)
            {
                sfLatLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(countryList.get(i).latitude),Double.parseDouble(countryList.get(i).longitude));
                //sfLatLng = new LatLng(dblatt, dblong);
                String buname = countryList.get(i).deal_id+"-"+countryList.get(i).deal_name;
                Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(sfLatLng)
                        .title(buname)
                        .snippet(countryList.get(i).deal_description)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.imgmapfullredpin)));
                dlid = countryList.get(i).deal_id;
                dlname = countryList.get(i).deal_name;
                catname = countryList.get(i).category_name;
                dldesc = countryList.get(i).deal_description;
                distan = countryList.get(i).distance;
                retailadd = countryList.get(i).retailer_address;
                dllat = countryList.get(i).latitude;
                dllng = countryList.get(i).longitude;
                totdeal = countryList.get(i).totdeals;

            }


            googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                public View getInfoWindow(Marker m1) {
                    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                            R.layout.balloon_map_overlay, null);
                    TextView tite = (TextView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    TextView snip = (TextView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.textView3);

                    if (m1.getTitle() != null) {
                        String str=m1.getTitle();
                        String[] strsg = str.split("-");


                        System.out.println(strsg[0]);
                        strpassid=strsg[0].toString();

                        System.out.println(strsg[1]);
                        tite.setText(strsg[1]);
                        //tite.setText(m1.getTitle());
                    }
                    if (m1.getSnippet() != null) {
                        String strh=m1.getSnippet();
                        System.out.println(strh);
                        snip.setText(m1.getSnippet());
                        //snip.setText(m1.getSnippet());
                    }



                    return v;
                }

                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                    return null;
                }
            });

            googleMap
                    .setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

                        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newLatLng(sfLatLng));
                            googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
                        }
                    });
            googleMap
                    .setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker item) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                            Intent viewdeal = new Intent(
                                    getApplicationContext(), ViewDealMap.class);
                            viewdeal.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            viewdeal.putExtra("dealid", strpassid);
                            startActivity(viewdeal);
                            overridePendingTransition(
                                    R.anim.slide_in_right,
                                    R.anim.slide_out_left);


                        }
                    });
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Setting a custom info window adapter for the google map
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

```
        // Use default InfoWindow frame
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);



            // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
            TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);

            // Setting the longitude
            tvLng.setText("any text");

                // declare a button wit onclick listener

            // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
            return v;

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply , but i want to click of button event is separate to click of info window .. in my case when i click to button then info window click works ... but i want to click on button of info window